# How can I check if $max_viewers is greater than $current_viewers?

Tags: php, operators

I have a script that updates the information of various livestream channels while they are active. I want to check if $max_viewers is greater than $current_viewers.

In this case I do not need to take action, however if $current_viewers is larger I want to update the max_viewers field in the database.

I have tried several ways and methods from research, but my PHP is limited and self taught and I think I am misunderstanding the outcome of my statements.

I have tried:

```
$current_viewers > $max_viewers
$current_viewers >= $max_viewers
```

But these seem to always update the max_viewer count, or never if reversed. Hence I think I am misunderstanding how these work and what they return.

Comment: Post some code, example data, database structure script or we can't help you

Answer (score 1):

You should have something like:

```
$max_viewers = 4;
$current_viewers = 2;

if ($current_viewers > $max_viewers) {
    // Current viewers has exceeded the maximum
    echo 'exceeded';
} else {
    // Current viewers is either less than or equal to the maximum
    echo 'not exceeded';
}
```

In the above example, `not exceeded` would be shown. For your example, you probably want to replace `echo 'exceeded';` with your call to update the database record.

Comment: I am not sure how I managed to mess this up. Thank you very much, your code works flawlessly.